# Symfony - modifying default data in prototypes

Tags: php, symfony, prototype

So say I have a `Category` and a `Product` entity, where `Category` has many `Product` entities. My `Category` form builder looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class) 
            ->add('products', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => ProductType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'prototype_name' => '__product_prot__'))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class))
        ;
    }
```

And my `Product` form builder looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class) 
            ->add('dateAdded', DateType::class)
        ;
    }
```

What I would like to know is how to set the value of `dateAdded` so that whenever a new prototype is added, it displays today's date?

Some people have suggested using the Entity `__construct()` function to create the default, but  this doesn't appear to work for prototypes. I've also found the [placeholder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#placeholder) option, but I'm not sure how to use it so that it always has today's date - i.e this doesn't appear to work:

```
->add('addDate', DateType::class, array(
    'placeholder' => new \DateTime();
))
```

As the error is: `Attempted to call function "DateTime" from the global namespace`

Additionally, I've found the [prototype_data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#prototype-data) field in the `CollectionType` field, but again, I'm not sure how to specify to only put data in a single field, and to make it dynamic.

Can someone tell me the best method to use - and the correct syntax?

**Edit:**

So my `__construct()` looks like:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->addDate = new \DateTime();
}
```

Which works fine for the `Category` entity (if I give it a date field for testing), but not the prototyped `Product` entity. When I load the prototype into the form, I just get a default date of 1st Jan 2011. The prototype looks like:

```
{% block _category_products_entry_row %}
    <li>
        {{ form_row(form.name) }}
        {{ form_row(form.dateAdded) }}
    </li>
{% endblock %}
```

Interestingly, I've also found if I load the new form with a `Product` entity created already in the `Category` controller, the `dateAdded` field that appears due to:

```
{% for product in form.products %}
     {{ form_row(product) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Has today's date as it's default value. This would suggest to me that the loading of the prototypes which is done in the same fashion as the [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) tutorial - is causing the issue.

Comment: `__construct` works with Form Builder prototypes. What does your constructor look like and what is the error?

Comment: Added my constructor, and there's not error if I try and set the `DateTime` in it, it just defaults to a basic value. The same thing if I give `DateTime` an argument like `now` or `today`.

Comment: Huh, you're constructor is normal, that's good. What basic value is being set?

Comment: 1st of Jan 2011. I made a few other classes and they all default to this specific value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a default value to a form field, you can use "data" property and use FormEvent to handle form on update. Here is the result:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class) 
        ->add('dateAdded', DateType::class, array(
            'data' => new \DateTime(),
        ))
    ;

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
        $product = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (!$product) {
            return;
        }

        if ($dateAdded = $product->getDateAdded()) {
            $form->add('dateAdded', DateType::class, array(
                'data' => $dateAdded,
            ));
        }
    });
}
```

On PRE_SET_DATA, you can override the default value on the dateAdded field with the data you fetched.

For more info, you can visit http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#data and https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html

Hope it helps

Comment: So the issue with that approach is that if you attempt to edit a form, it overwrites the saved data with the form `'data'`.